# Combine nodes by categorical attribute in Gephi

Tags: gephi, network-analysis

I'm working on a visualization of organizational structure in Gephi. I have a graph of individuals, connected by whether or not they have worked together in the past. Graphing individuals looks good, but I would like to combine nodes (individuals) based on a categorical attribute (department; string). The new graph -- or at least a visualization -- would have a node for every department, preferably with a numerical weight proportional to how many individuals comprise it.

I could do this in the scripts that generate the graph files before importing. But I did exactly this about a year ago entirely in Gephi. Either the functionality was removed ([like the pie charts](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/1101)!) or I've just forgotten (more likely).

Am using Gephi 0.9.1. Any help, much appreciated.